# Verification solution to simple IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, initial-value-problems

My textbook states:

> The function
>   $$u(t) = t^2$$
>
> is a solution to the IVP:
>
> $$u'(t) = 2\sqrt{|u(t)|}\hspace{30pt}u(0) =0$$

and I'm a little bit confused, since $u'(-10) = -20 \neq 20 = 2\cdot10 = 2\cdot\sqrt{100} = 2\cdot\sqrt{(-10)^2}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything. $t^{2}$ is not  a solution of the IVP on  $\mathbb R$. It is a solution on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. It's strange: The complete example in my textbook is:  The IVP
$u′ = 2\sqrt{|u|}, u(0) = 0$
has solutions $u(t) = t^2$ and $u(t) = 0$ that both exist for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (global existence, but
non-uniqueness).